# .php pages download instead of opening in a browser

Tags: php, browser, download

I've found lots of posts telling of how to force a browser to download a file instead of opening it, but I'm a bit confounded as to why my files, which are meant to open in a browser, are sent to download instead.

These are .php pages, which worked perfectly under the previous URL.  They have been uploaded to the same server under a new URL, but I'm not sure what needs to be adjusted for them to open in a browser correctly.

Comment: Sounds like your sever configuration on the new URL is wrong.

Comment: You might want to consider taking the new site offline until you get the issue resolved because until then, anyone can download and view your server-side PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you do no have a .php file handler for your new site.

As such when such a file is encountered by the web server, it presents it as a download rather than running it through php.

Check your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It means that your server is not able to render html from that php page.

So there may be some problem with the server as it is not processing the php content inside the file.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you're going to need to go into the control panel, or whatever other management interface your hosting provider offers, and enable PHP support on the new URL.

How to do this varies depending on which interface your host provides, but in most of the tools that I've seen it's simply labelled as 'PHP' and you probably need to simply turn it on.